# Techniques for accurate 5.5 Vdc active voltage clamp

Tags: over-voltage-protection

We are currently using TI ISOW7841 Digital Isolation modules /w built-in isolated 5 Vdc DC-DC converter [Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sllsey2e/sllsey2e.pdf).  We are having rare failures.  Failure shows up as the module running much hotter than normal.  The module appears to continue to work correctly for some time before failing completely.

Because we have had only 3 failures so far, it is hard to pinpoint the cause.  However, I suspect that the input DC supply line (5 Vdc) is having transients that exceed the module's maximum allowable input voltage of 6.0 Vdc.

The 5 Vdc supply normally comes from a -48V POE (Power Over Ethernet) DC-DC converter module (AG9905MT from Silvertel [Datasheet](https://www.silvertel.com/images/datasheets/Ag9900M-datasheet-ultra-miniature-isolated-Power-over-Ethernet-POE-module.pdf)).  There is also a connector for an external 5 Vdc supply for when POE is not available.

I want to add an accurate clamp device or circuit that will not allow the 5V rail to exceed about 5.75 Vdc.  I am not aware of any such devices on the market.  Accordingly, I probably have to build this myself.

It needs to be fast - response time better than 1us or faster.

It needs to be accurate - the margin between voltage okay and too high is quite small.

It needs to be small - PCB layout is already done and there is not much room left to allow the PCB to fit in the enclosure.

Obviously, big-ass Zener diodes or Tranzorbs are out, simply because they are not sufficiently accurate.

I'm currently thinking about using the ubiquitous TL431 driving a low-gate-threshold-voltage (TrenchFET) P-channel MOSFET but would appreciate other opinions.  In particular, I don't think that the TL431 is fast enough.

If anyone can suggest devices that already do this function, I would gladly explore those first.  Other circuit approaches also appreciated.

{Edit}

I've since become aware of devices with tradename of Polyzen (From Littlefuse).  I'm currently looking at the version rated at 5.8 Vdc [Datasheet](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/product_specifications/polyzen_devices/littelfuse_polyzen_zen056v115a24ls_product_specification.pdf.pdf).

That said: I'm still asking for opinions and alternative options.

Comment: If you suspect transients on +5V input, why don't you collect some evidence using an oscilloscope? Are there spikes? How high and how long they are? Maybe just a good capacitor can do the job?

Comment: Three failures over several thousand hours of operation. No anomalies observed any time we have put a scope on the supply rail. Sort of grasping at straws here but the failures are consistent with transient over-voltage.

Comment: Thousand hours of nominal operations maybe not a probable state of failure. How about thousand on-off-on cycles? Are there any signs of voltage spikes?

Comment: Probably only high hundreds of on-off cycles.  Failures all occurred in the field.  It is impractical to have a scope connected to the device for any length of time in the field.

Comment: I am not suggesting to hook up scopes in the field. I am merely suggesting to take one of your devices on lab bench and cycle the power in various ways, imitating brown-out conditions, rapid on-off-on. etc, and try to determine if there are **any indications** for potential overvoltage. If not, you need to look elsewhere.